# Transfer function of two frequency spectra

Tags: frequency, torque, fourier, frequency-response, ripple

When you have two amplitude frequency spectra (fourier spectrum), in this case of a torque ripple, how do you define the transfer function (or the ratio) between both? How do you "divide" the spectra to see where they differ the most?

Shown below is an example of the spectrum of the ripple measured at the output of a transmission.

[image]

For my thesis, I want to define a KPI from: a transfer function of a torque ripple applied to the input of a transmission and the transfer function of the same torque ripple measured at the output of the transmission.

Simply put, I want to define a ratio between the input torque ripple and the one at the output to see if the transmission in between excites this ripple at certrain rpm's (because of misalignments, TE, etc.)

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

The transfer function is indeed the ratio of amplitudes or **differences in Spectrum plots** and are great KPI's for quality in manufacturing and maintenance if you develop acceptance criteria.

When it comes to a transmission that scales frequency through a number of gears the input spectrum gets multiplied and filtered according to damping or smoothness of gear meshing as well as the nonlinearity of sum and difference frequencies from each exciter or mover f.

The transfer function will be dependent on the RPM but may be reciprocal.
You can dampen out primary resonances with a bigger flywheel for testing but you will need an acoustic Network Analyzer(NA) to examine A, B and B/A.  The NA has 3 ports; Oscillator OSC out, In A, In B.

Ball bearing wear will have different harmonics from a sleeve bearing fundamentals and nonlinearities may also exist with aliasing with the actual signal being higher frequency than expected during the sampling and Fourier Analysis.

For another type of test, consider hypothetically using the OSC out to inject current noise in your motor current (error amplifier) then see what the gain is from A to B in the transmission.  This may require a tracking filter to match the OSC out to prevent adding harmonic content but depending on the error tolerance you need it will eliminate the motor spectrum, like adding an infinite flywheel.
Spectral contents from vibration are certainly good key performance indicators (KPI).

Your output spectrum shows a dominant spectrum at f=4.2kHz/at 5200 RPM= 86.667 Hz with lower content at 0.5f , 2f, 3f and something at 750 Hz but no DC value of torque.

Another approach is to use a DSO to compute the difference in Fourier spectrum for B-A gain using the PC to process the data. There are software tools you may be familiar with to compute these Fourier Spectrum.

There are also **Modal Analyzers** using 3D impulse response from a plastic hammer. I've used these for large housing servos to examine baseplate resonances for opportunities in structural changes to avoid these.

Also maybe is looking at step load response in acceleration with **magnetic wheel encoders** by Infineon used in some cars that have many (>200) steps per rev. and or mounting 3D accelerometers looking for vibration noise in the housing. Then plot the 3-phase motor torque spectrum over top with all other known exciters and KPI points and take the difference as some misalignment resonance.

But I think baseplate 3D accelerometer noise is a must-have R&D accessory for alignment/wear or KPI indicators.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was more looking for a mathematical approach however. An operation that allows me to define a ratio between the input and output fourier transformations.

Comment: When you use Spectrum the transfer function is just the difference.  In the time domain you need to sweep a bandpass filter and take the peak amplitude and phase difference for a Bode plot with a signal, then compute ratios.  You cannot simply compute where there is no frequency or noise and get 0/0=? It is done with a sweep signal

Comment: If you cannot understand the process then the math is useless but since it is simple to understand, it is easy to do.